# How to carry out changes to unique_together constraint from one set of model fields to another in Django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, unique-constraint

In my Django project I have the following **model**:

```
class TenderOrigin(models.Model):
    doc_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, ...)
    doc_short_txt = models.CharField(max_length=150, ...)
    create_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, ...)
    port_grp = models.ForeignKey(PortGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, ...)
#    frt_grp = models.ForeignKey(FrtGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, ...)
    locn_from = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, ...)
    tender_number = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True,...)
    tender_date = models.DateField(null=True, ...)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['locn_from__LocName']
#        unique_together = [['frt_grp', 'locn_from', 'tender_date'],]    # Original constraint
        unique_together = [['port_grp', 'locn_from', 'tender_date'],]    # New constraint being defined
```

As noted (against the unique constraints' defn.) above, I am trying to change the original **unique_together** constraint to the new one (using field `port_grp`). The change is necessitated by a new field (`port_grp`) that is being added to the model, while field `frt_grp` is being removed.

However, while migrating I am getting following error message:

```
...
...    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
...
...
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: matmovt_tenderorigin.port_grp_id, matmovt_tenderorigin.locn_from_id, matmovt_tenderorigin.tender_date
```

Is it possible to change **unique_together** constraint as defined for one set of **fields**, to another (without deleting existing data)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach it.

1. Create new fields as needed on your model.
2. Create the migration for the new fields.
3. Create data migration to populate the new fields
4. Create UniqueConstraint and drop the old unique constraint.
5. Generate the migration for the constraint changes. Be sure the drop is after the create. Though it should all run in a transaction so it shouldn't matter.
6. Drop old fields.

If your data migration will create data that violates the old unique constraint, then drop that before doing the data migration. Obviously this is pretty risky because now you're allowing the system itself to generate data that could be invalid making a rollback / reverse migration very painful.